# How to convert this specific bookmarklet to a greasemonkey script

Tags: javascript, sorting, greasemonkey

I have little to no coding experience and I am trying to see if anyone can help me with turning this bookmarklet to greasemonkey format:

```
javascript: function toArray(c) {
    var a, k;
    a = new Array;
    for (k = 0; k < c.length; ++k) a[k] = c[k];
    return a;
}

function insAtTop(par, child) {
    if (par.childNodes.length) par.insertBefore(child, par.childNodes[0]);
    else par.appendChild(child);
}

function countCols(tab) {
    var nCols, i;
    nCols = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < tab.rows.length; ++i)
        if (tab.rows[i].cells.length > nCols) nCols = tab.rows[i].cells.length;
    return nCols;
}

function makeHeaderLink(tableNo, colNo, ord) {
    var link;
    link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = 'javascript:sortTable(' + tableNo + ',' + colNo + ',' + ord + ');';
    link.appendChild(document.createTextNode((ord > 0) ? 'a' : 'd'));
    return link;
}

function makeHeader(tableNo, nCols) {
    var header, headerCell, i;
    header = document.createElement('tr');
    for (i = 0; i < nCols; ++i) {
        headerCell = document.createElement('td');
        headerCell.appendChild(makeHeaderLink(tableNo, i, 1));
        headerCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode('/'));
        headerCell.appendChild(makeHeaderLink(tableNo, i, -1));
        header.appendChild(headerCell);
    }
    return header;
}
g_tables = toArray(document.getElementsByTagName('table'));
if (!g_tables.length) alert("This page doesn't contain any tables.");
(function() {
    var j, thead;
    for (j = 0; j < g_tables.length; ++j) {
        thead = g_tables[j].createTHead();
        insAtTop(thead, makeHeader(j, countCols(g_tables[j])))
    }
})();

function compareRows(a, b) {
    if (a.sortKey == b.sortKey) return 0;
    return (a.sortKey < b.sortKey) ? g_order : -g_order;
}

function sortTable(tableNo, colNo, ord) {
    var table, rows, nR, bs, i, j, temp;
    g_order = ord;
    g_colNo = colNo;
    table = g_tables[tableNo];
    rows = new Array();
    nR = 0;
    bs = table.tBodies;
    for (i = 0; i < bs.length; ++i)
        for (j = 0; j < bs[i].rows.length; ++j) {
            rows[nR] = bs[i].rows[j];
            temp = rows[nR].cells[g_colNo];
            if (temp) rows[nR].sortKey = temp.innerHTML;
            else rows[nR].sortKey = "";
            ++nR;
        }
    rows.sort(compareRows);
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i) insAtTop(table.tBodies[0], rows[i]);
}
```

It runs perfectly fine when I trigger it from the bookmark, and I've tried various solutions listed on this website but it doesn't trigger itself even when its enabled in greasemonkey!
I tried the decoding method and tried to put onload in front of the code. Sorry I don't really know how to code.. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's Url encoded.  You need to decode it and you will have regular Javascript.  Also it's incomplete.  Either way, here - https://www.urldecoder.org

Comment: I tried copypasting the code from the bookmarklet properties but it doesn't show up properly, I used the decoder, what else do I need to do?

Comment: I don't use Greasemonkey, but with Tampermonkey I'd have the script set to run on page load and I'd just paste the above into it (remove the `javascript:` from the beginning though).

Answer (score 0):

Your bookmarklet is encoded so it will be having invalid javascript tokens , You will required to decode it first using online tool or `decodeURIComponent` function in javascript console.

Once done you can use any beautifier site to prettify and use in GreaseMonkey.

Hope that helps !!